# How to change the color of a view widget which is placed in the ListView on clicking the ListView row?

Tags: android, listview

I have generated a Slider ListView. At present I am able to highlight and keep the row highlighted for the selected fragment. I also have a  `view` element which is not set to any color at present. I want to highlight this view with an orange color when the ListView is clicked. How can I do this? The codes that I used to highlight the Listview row are as follows; kindly guide me step by step.

listselector.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_normal" android:state_activated="false"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
<item android:drawable="@drawable/list_item_bg_pressed" android:state_activated="true"/>

</selector>
```

list_item_bg_pressed

```
   <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background_pressed"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

list_itm_bg_normal

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle">
 <gradient
  android:startColor="@color/list_background"
  android:endColor="@color/list_background"
  android:angle="90" />
</shape>
```

activity_main.xml

```
  <ListView
    android:id="@+id/left_drawer"
     android:listSelector="@drawable/list_selector"
    android:background="@color/list_background"
    android:layout_width="240dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
    android:dividerHeight="0dp"
    />
```

Comment: set the selector to the required view

Comment: @Ann check my answer below, its working fine for me to highlight ListView row.

Answer (score 0):

Try below code, its working for me:

```
   YOUR VIEW.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            holder.lnrMainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_bg_square_selected);
                            final Timer timer = new Timer();
                            timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    getActivity().runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                                        @Override
                                        public void run() {
                                            try {
                                                holder.lnrMainLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.home_bg_square);
                                                launchActivity(obj);
                                                timer.cancel();
                                            } catch (Throwable e) {
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }
                                        }
                                    });

                                }
                            }, 500, 500);

                        }
                    });
```

Set Whatever background you want instead of my background in above code.